# disable ngx-bootstrap popover?

Tags: angular, popover, ngx-bootstrap, ngx-bootstrap-popover

Is there a way for a popover to not show over the label if it doesn't meet the condition?

```html
<label [popover]-"popTemplate" popoverTitle="Nicknames">{{label}}</label>

<ng-template #popTemplate>
<li *ngFor="let names of nickNames">
      {{ names }}
    </li>
</ng-template>
```

Is there something like `[isDisabled]="!haveNickNames()"`? or use `ngIf` in some way?

Comment: You can have manual triggers instead of automatic and conditionally open it

Comment: ah ok, haha seems obvious now. Thank you! Sorry still a beginner programmer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the [documentation](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/popover#trigger-by-isopen-property), you can use the `isOpen` property

```html
<label [popover]="popTemplate" triggers="" [isOpen]="!haveNickNames">
  {{label}}
</label>
```